# Infinitely Looping Event in Velocity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, velocity

Good eve,

I'm having some issues with an onScroll event here:

http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/bEwmmJ

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 30 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 30) {
        /*
        $(".flower").velocity(
            "transition.expandIn", 
            {stagger: 0, duration:2000}
        ).delay(4000) 
        */
        $(".petal").velocity(
            "transition.expandIn", 
            {stagger: 25, drag:true, backwards:false, duration:2000}
        ).delay(4000) 
    } else {
    }
}
```

Everything there is functioning normally, but my event handler keeps on cycling and I really only want it to execute once. I'm relatively new to javascript, and I only started messing about with velocity a few hours ago -- I'd really appreciate some help here!

I tried `return false;` and it didn't seem to comprehend. I'm thinking that I should trigger the event with a different handler and stop trying to focus on where the scroll bar is, but this would be much quicker for me if I could get it working.

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the onscroll event handler? Maybe put a `window.onscroll = null` inside your myFunction to remove the handler after the petal initialization?

Comment: I'm making a parallax site and I want different animations to play once when they come into view, I figured the best way would be to make events for each animation (1 per page).

Comment: If you want the animation to be displayed only once, then you can add a `window.onscroll=null;` right after the velocity animation initialization.
Also, you can drop the first function on the event handler. Instead use `window.onscroll = myFunction;`

Comment: The `window.onscroll = null` clears (resets) the onscroll event handler.
@joel

Comment: Thank you - I haven't tried it yet, as I've had to put that project on a hold while I do some other jobs. I hate freelancing so much, but it forces me to learn a lot of stuff while trying to fulfill clients' requests.